# No more badges?

Tags: bug, badges

The "Select your next badge" menu seems to think there are no badges:

[image]

All five tabs are empty like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same issue in the past. All you need to do is click "let us pick". It will choose one for you. Then, you should be able to change it to whichever badge you want.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score -3):

The explanation of the cause of this is [available on the main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333175/next-tag-badge-selector-doesnt-show-all-available-choices#comment1087007_333175).

Comment by [Sonic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/377214/sonic-the-anonymous-hedgehog?tab=activity&sort=all):

"The badges you **can't track** all correspond to **tags with fewer than 100 questions**, which are ineligible for tag badges.", and [animuson's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) answer and [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323090/282094).

All [our badges](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=all) are, as of now, ineligible; whereas [on main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=all) (and many other sites) many badges appear in that [modal](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/modal-web-design#:%7E:text=A%20modal%20(also%20called%20a,action%20or%20by%20closing%20it.), where their badges have more usage.

Further clarification due to comment and DVs:

It shows the tag badges (and none are eligible), see here: ["Track the next one" window shows tag badges instead of normal badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377181/282094) and here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375146/282094 - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253570/282094 --- "However, if click on "Track the next one", I get a popup showing all tag badges instead of the normal badges.".

[Some badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273929/282094) can't be tracked due to performance issues. Also explained here: [On private beta sites the "Select your next badge" popup isn't populated from the "Track the next one" button, but works fine from "Let us pick"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376787/on-private-beta-sites-the-select-your-next-badge-popup-isnt-populated-from-th#comment1255832_376787)

You need to choose "Let us pick" to activate the ***Cog*** which then allows you to change from Tag Tracking to Badge Tracking:

[image]

As you can see it *works* for me here on this site:

[image]

Comment: That's about _tag_ badges though; I was asking about the regular badges that every site has.